# Set condition to the combobox list content in UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Currently I am creating a simple user form for adding of new projects into the sheets. However, one problem I am facing now is that I have three different ranges of rows that consist of three different sizes of projects and their details. For example row 1 to 100 consist of big projects details, while row 150 to 250 is medium projects and row 300 to 400 is small project details. Thus by using the combo dropdown list, the user will select "big project" or "medium project" or "small project".

Thereafter, the new project details will be inserted into the new rows found in the sheet, based on the project sizes that they have selected, in the combo box drop down list.

I have the code below to get me started but am not sure how to proceed:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ComboBoxProjSizes
    .AddItem "Big Project"
    .AddItem "Medium Project"
    .AddItem "Small Project"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What should happen when, say, the user selects `"Big Project"`

Comment: the project details will be inserted into the lastrow of the big project range when the user select "Big Projects". this same goes to the "Medium Project" and "Small project" @SiddharthRout

Comment: I don't think you understood my question... or maybe I didn't understand yours :D You have big projects in cells 1 to 100. So if the user selects `"Big Project"` from the combobox then what should happen?

Comment: All the project details that the user input into the form will be registered to the next empty row of the big project range @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deside what happends if an item of your `combobox` is selected, for example:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxProjSizes_Change()
Dim projectsheet As Worksheet
Set projectsheet = Sheets("Table1") 'change as needed

If ComboBoxProjSizes = "Big Project" Then
 Dim BigRange As Range
 Set BigRange = projectsheet.Range("A1:A100") 'define your range for "Big Project"
 BigRange.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select 'select first emoty cell in the range
 'here you can copy your cell with Big Project
Else
 'check the other inputs
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi is it possible if you could show me some example of the codes that could be inserted on the 'add new row as you want line. I am unsure of the codes to insert for that particular line @katz